# How to send a picture (or retrieve from printers memory) through raw IPL?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ipl

I am printing labels on an Intermec printer via IP and have been asked to add our company logo to the label. In other applications I am able to break apart a bitmap and send raw ZPL, but I can't figure it out in IPL. I would also settle for saving the image on the printers, but I can't figure out how to retrieve it to print.
Here is my simple procedure, any help would be great!

```
Dim clientSocket As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
        clientSocket.Connect(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 9100))
        Dim Format As String = "<STX><ESC>C<ETX> Select Advanced mode" &
                               "<STX><ESC>P<ETX> Enter Program mode" &
                               "<STX>E22;F22;<ETX> Erase format 22, create format 22" &
                               "<STX>H0;o520,50;f0;c26;h12;w12;d0,50;<ETX> Edit/create human-readable field 0" &
                               "<STX>H1;o520,90;f0;c26;h12;w12;d0,50;<ETX> Edit/create human-readable field 1" &
                               "<STX>H2;o520,130;f0;c26;h12;w12;d0,50;<ETX> Edit/create human-readable field 2" &
                               "<STX>H3;o50,340;f0;c26;h12;w12;d0,50;<ETX> Edit/create human-readable field 3" &
                               "<STX>H4;o50,380;f0;c26;h12;w12;d0,50;<ETX> Edit/create human-readable field 4" &
                               "<STX>H5;o50,420;f0;c26;h12;w12;d0,50;<ETX> Edit/create human-readable field 5" &
                               "<STX>H6;o50,535;f0;c26;h12;w12;d0,50;<ETX> Edit/create human-readable field 6" &
                               "<STX>L8;o30,30;f0;l760;w3;<ETX> Edit/create line field 8" &
                               "<STX>L9;o30,580;f0;l760;w3;<ETX> Edit/create line field 9" &
                               "<STX>L10;o790,31;f3;l550;w3;<ETX> Edit/create line field 10" &
                               "<STX>L11;o29,580;f1;l550;w3;<ETX> Edit/create line field 11" &
                               "<STX>R;<ETX> Save format and exit to Print mode"

        Dim PrintData As String = "<STX><ESC>E22<ETX> Access format 22" &
                                  "<STX><CAN><ETX> Erase all data" &
                                  "<STX>DATE: 7/17/2020<CR><ETX> Data for human-readable field 0" &
                                  "<STX>LWO # 118826<CR><ETX> Data for human-readable field 1" &
                                  "<STX>QUANTITY: 5<CR><ETX> Data for human-readable field 2" &
                                  "<STX>LEE P/N & REV: PCHX0024024S A<CR><ETX> Data for human-readable field 3" &
                                  "<STX>DESCRIPTION:<CR><ETX> Data for human-readable field 4" &
                                  "<STX>LEE RELIEF VALVE, 8mm, INSERT, REVERSE, 241 BAR<CR><ETX> Data for human-readable field 5" &
                                  "<STX>CUSTOMER: Parker Hannifin<CR><ETX> Data for human-readable field 6" &
                                  "<STX><RS><ETB><ETX> Print "
        Dim Label As String = Format & PrintData

        clientSocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Label))
        clientSocket.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was able to do this by saving the picture to the printer.

The first step was to make a monochrome bitmap the correct size and scale.
Next you have to rename it UDCn.LOGO - where n=a number you will later reference.
Save it to the printer.

Then call it in the code

```
<STX>U1;o200,400;f1;c1;w1;h1;<ETX>
```

- note c1 calls UDC1.LOGO

Another thing to consider is that you can't scale down the picture. w1;h1 is actual size (by pixels), so getting you image the correct size is done outside of the IPL code unless you want to make it bigger.